# Teach me to get the variable through the class

Tags: actionscript-3

Thanks you for seeing my post. I am making a game. I am working in enemy class. I want the enemy follow the player if the distance is near enough. And i have a problem here. I can't get the playerx and playery. This is my class:
Main.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var player:Player;


        public function Main():void
        {
            player = new Player
            player.x=400;
            player.y=300;
            stage.addChild(player);
        }
    }
}
```

enemy.as

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class enemy extends MovieClip {

        public var enemyhp:Number=100;

        public function enemy() {
            // constructor code
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enemyLoop);
        }
        function enemyLoop(e:Event):void
        {
            trace(Player.playerx);
            trace(Player.playery);
        }
    }

}
```

Player.as

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Player extends MovieClip {

        public var playerx:Number;
        public var playery:Number;

        public function Player() {
            // constructor code
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, returnxy);
        }
        function returnxy(e:Event):void
        {
            playerx=x;
            playery=y;
        }
    }

}
```

and this is my error:
D:\Testtestest\enemy.as, Line 18    1119: Access of possibly undefined property playerx through a reference with static type Class.
D:\Testtestest\enemy.as, Line 19    1119: Access of possibly undefined property playery through a reference with static type Class.

Sorry because my english is not good. I am Vietnamese, and i am a new in coding.I want to coding with Class like a pro. Thanks you very much. <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use the player's `playerx` & `playery` properties like they are static properties (that is, belonging to the class, not the instance).  You need to gain a reference to the instance of your player, or make the properties static.
There are few ways to accomplish this, here is one way that is quick, though not necessarily the cleanest:

In your Player class, create a static variable to store the singleton instance of your player:

```
public static var me:Player;
```

Then in the constructor of the player class (that is the method named `Player`), assign `this` to the `me` var:

```
me = this;
```

Now you have a static reference to your player instance, and you can access it's public properties & methods anywhere in your app by doing `Player.me`,   for instance `Player.me.x`

What this does, is anytime you create a new Player instance, it assigns that instance to the Player class's `me` var.  Presumably you only have one Player instance at any given time.

Now, static methods and vars should be used with care, as they persist for the whole life-cycle of you application.  Some developers endeavor to use static as little as possible (or just for constants and settings) and I generally would agree with them, that said, putting some static properties on a display object isn't that bad as long as you clean up after yourself properly.  (eg. `null` the `me` reference if you're no longer wanting the player in memory)

Of course, there are lots of other ways to get your Player instance, like doing `MovieClip(root).player` (not a fan of that syntax but it works) or injecting it into your enemy from the common parent with (`new Enemy(player)`) or having a class that manages all the enemies and the player together.  If you have time, I'd search around for some of the best practices for game programming patterns.

Comment: Wow! Thanks you so much, it so helpful.Thanks you anyway.

Comment: Incredible! It work, your coding skill is so pro! Thanks you so much

Comment: Thank you so much so much. It is very helpful! Before i see this post, my game code is not clean and it have a lot of disadvanted in my code. Sorry because my EL is not good.

Comment: The best practices for game programming patterns please!The best practices for game programming patterns please! Thanks you so much